# Pikuach Nefesh and different levels of Halacha

Tags: halacha, priorities, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, derabanan, deorayta

Here's a theoretical: if someone has to save a life and has two equally easy options, both of which violate halacha, one d'oraita and one d'rabbanan. Should he choose the d'oraita or the d'rabbanan?

Answer (score 13):

At least with regards to hilchos Shabbos, you should choose the derabannan.

See שמירת שבת כהלכתה לב:כז-כח*, who writes that if there is no difference in speed or quality of care, that one should choose to do a rabbinically prohibited action, instead of one that is Biblically prohibited.

I don't know if this is Shabbos-specific, or if this rule applies universally.

---

* *Second edition, red cover*